# Each button click adds text to current label objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to the Objective-c language. I'm trying to create an app that has a button and a label. The button should display some text which I did already. The only problem is that when I click the button, it only adds the specified text once. I want it to keep adding the same text to the label each I time I press the button.

Here is my .h file

```
{

IBOutlet UILabel *label;

}

-(IBAction)btnClcik:(id)sender;
```

Here is the .m file

```
-(IBAction)btnClcik:(id)sender
{

label.text=@"test";

}
```

Comment: Remember! `stringByAppendingString:` and `stringByAppendingFormat:` would work when your `Label` has some text initially...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to the string?

Then do

```
label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", textToAdd];
```

where `textToAdd` is a NSString or some other valid object where `%@` is the correct format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

To append to the existing text, use the string's concatenation method...

```
label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString:@"test"];
```